# What are the two white plugs on a Zoeller sump pump used for

Tags: pump, sump-pump

I've done the trouble-shooting for stoppage of my Zoeller (M53).  I un-did screws on both
top switch-housing and the lower housing where motor-coil is visible (with a 10uF white capacitor
about size and shape of a 9-volt battery zip-tied onto motor coil).

Capacitor looks fine visually.  The switch looked fine and clicks nicely up and down.  But, I
put my meter into continuity-mode, the switch tests 'open' when in both up and down positions.
That's consistent with my symptom: that the pump doesn't turn on when float-bob switches up.

[I've heard that Zoeller pumps (from YouTube repair videos) are 'known' for having switch-failures.]

The pump is only about 2 years old.  So, I decided to try REPAIRING this one, rather than just
buying a new pump (approx $200 on Amazon).  I ordered the $48 replacement switch, and
replacing that seems very straight-forward.

My question concerns the two white-plastic threaded plugs in the side of the pump.one on upper compartment (where the switch is), and another is down on the lower part containing the
pump motor windings.

I think I read that oil/fluid is to be put into the lower chamber.  How much to put and where can I buy such fluid?

I get why the lower base could want such fluid.  (Though I thought that sump-water passes thru there and could be a coolant!?)  But, what I REALLY don't understand is why the upper (switch)
section has exactly the same-sized 'filler hole"???  Putting any kind of fluid into that compartment seems goofy, as it appears 'dry-as-a-bone'.  So, what (if anything) is supposed to be put into that switch compartment???

Answer (score 1):

After about 10 days, I've now received the replacement switch that I
ordered on Amazon.  It comes with very detailed instructions for all the steps to install and test the switch replacement.

Although it doesn't explicitly say anything about the white plug, it DOES talk about PRESSURE TESTING (at 2 to 3 PSI), after you've replaced the switch and tightened down the switch cover plate.  So,
I've deduced that both upper and lower white plugs are to allow one to inject air or to attach a pressure gauge, to test each chamber.

These instructions do NOT discuss anything about inspecting or testing the lower (motor) chamber, so I'm still in the dark about
whether some fluid needs to be be added/checked, or whatever.

But this answer DOES solve this posting's query about the purpose of the two white plugs, so I'm accepting my answer as the solution. That said, tho, I should add that I do NOT understand what devices/tools are needed for such pressure test, nor how to use any such tools to carry out the test.

Also, in the base question, I mentioned rumor that some fluid is supposed to be added into the base (pump) chamber.  So, if anyone comes along and reads this entry and has info on these extra issues, please feel free to post info into either an additional answer or as a comment.

Comment: I have replaced seals in submersible pumps, and the rebuild manual says to test with a hand vacuum pump. You pump it to a set vacuum level per the gauge on the pump, and watch that it can hold vacuum for some set interval.

Comment: It would be considerate to _actually_ accept the answer instead of just leaving it hanging.